# Best approach to create an saturating integer in python?

Tags: python-2.7

What would be the best approach to create a type that is a saturated integer in python ?

i.e.:

```
v = SaturatedInteger(0, 100) 
# That should create an integer that will always be in between 0 and 100,
# and have all default operations

v += 68719
print v #Should print '100'.
```

I can think of inheriting `int` type, but where should the saturating logic be implemented then ?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types

Comment: I'm just curious: Is saturating like clamping (a term I've seen in OpenGL)?

Comment: @DavidEhrmann clamping is the term used when the range is fixed via a separate step, while saturating is where the limit is applied during the operation itself. The result of either should be identical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need a new (quick and dirty) class for it, I would implement it as follows.

```
class SaturatedInteger:
    def __init__(self, val, lo, hi):
        self.real, self.lo, self.hi = val, lo, hi

    def __add__(self, other):
        return min(self.real + other.real, self.hi)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return max(self.real - other.real, self.lo)

    ...
```

Add as many of the other operators in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) as you feel you will need (and their '`r`' variants).

By storing the value in the instance name `real`, you can do your arithmetic with regular integers, floats, etc. too:

```
a = SaturatedInteger(60, 0, 100)
print(a)
60
print(a+30)
90
print(a+40)
100
print(a+50.)
100
print(a-70.)
0
print(a+a)
100
```

Though, of course you only add the real part if you're adding a complex number to your `SaturatedInteger`, so watch out.  (For a much more complete and robust version, @jonrsharpe's answer is the way to go).

Comment: the `.real` is a nice approach, it increases interoperability.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I would implement using a `@property` to protect an instance's `value` attribute, then [emulate a numeric type](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types), rather than inheriting from `int`:

```
class SaturatedInteger(object):
    """Emulates an integer, but with a built-in minimum and maximum."""

    def __init__(self, min_, max_, value=None):
        self.min = min_
        self.max = max_
        self.value = min_ if value is None else value

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, new_val):
        self._value = min(self.max, max(self.min, new_val))

    @staticmethod
    def _other_val(other):
        """Get the value from the other object."""
        if hasattr(other, 'value'):
            return other.value
        return other

    def __add__(self, other):
        new_val = self.value + self._other_val(other)
        return SaturatedInteger(self.min, self.max, new_val)

    __radd__ = __add__

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.value == self._other_val(other)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    v = SaturatedInteger(0, 100)
    v += 68719
    assert v == 100
    assert 123 + v == 100
```

I've only implemented `__add__`, `__radd__` and `__eq__`, but you can probably see how the rest could be built out as required. You might want to think about what happens when two `SaturatedInteger`s are used together - should the result have e.g. `min(self.min, other.min)` as its own `min`?

Comment: That's a good answer with a very interesting question at the end :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a sample class that has an add function:

```
class SatInt:
    def __init__(self, low, up):
        self.lower = low
        self.upper = up
        self.value = 0

    def add(self, n):
        if n+self.value > self.upper:
            self.value = self.upper
        else:
            self.value = self.value + n


x = SatInt(0,100)
x.add(32718)
print(x.value)
```

> 100

Comment: Rather than `add`, you should implement `__add__` so that it can be used with `+`...